# Table header is unexpextedly shifted in firefox on monitors with big resolution

Tags: html, css, firefox, html-table

[image: how I see it, scaled by image editor]

I have encountered a problem with table headers in firefox, which appeard to me when viewing on monitors with big resolution (i.e. 1920x1080); the table header is shifted by 1 pixel.

I am trying to achieve the following: Internal borders - 1 pixel, external - 2px, header should have a different color.

I've removed some redundant code, but was left with 2 div blocks due necessity. The problem disappeared in other browsers, in other resolutions, when I resize browser window. But it reproduces on anther computer (Mac).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>

    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
            }
            table.border {
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            table.border td {
                background-color: #ffffff;
                border: 1px #CCCCCC solid;
            }
            table.border td:first-child {
                border-left-width: 2px;
            }
            table.border td:last-child {
                border-right-width: 2px;
            }
            table.border th {
                background-color: #767676;
                border: #CCCCCC solid;
                border-width: 0px 1px;
                color: #ffffff
            }
            table.border th:first-child {
                border-left: #767676 solid 2px;
            }
            table.border th:last-child {
                border-right: #767676 solid 2px;
            }
            table.border {
                border: #CCCCCC solid;
                border-width: 0px 0px 2px 0px;
            }
            #all {
                max-width: 1400px;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
            }
        </style>
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="all">
            <table class="border">
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>test</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Eliran Malka has right, but maybe you can do some workaround, too.

In this example the `table.border` has no border, but you can add a 'bordered' `div` after it. If you modify the `#all` element to hide the unnecessary `.footer_border` parts you get something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Stocki/mBQS2/2/

**Edit:**

For modern browsers it is possible to use the `::after` selector instead of `div`, so the HTML code stays clean:

http://jsfiddle.net/Stocki/mBQS2/4/

Comment: @Eliran Malka: Thanks for the comment, I added a new alternative. (workaround?)

Answer (score 2):

You got bitten by the infamous [**border-collapse bug**](http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2006/09/table_border_collapseborder_attribute_bug.html) (which affects 
webkit browsers as well, but differs in behavior; the background shifts to the other side). This bug has to do with different implementations in browsers when rounding ½ pixels.

*Ben Buchanan* wrote about this [on Opera's Web Standards Curriculum](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/33-styling-tables/#bordercollapse), which was later donated to the [W3C web education community group](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Styling_tables).

Here's an extract from the article, for the sake of completeness:

> … So what’s the solution? If you want to use a 1px border and a caption
>   background, there really isn’t a fix other than to "live with it ". It
>   is a very minor difference and a non-fatal problem—that is, the table
>   remains entirely usable. So, many people choose to just live with the
>   differences between browsers. Let the Web be the Web. If you are happy
>   to use a larger border, say 2px, then you can simply set a 1px border
>   on table, cells and caption; then set table to separate borders and
>   apply zero spacing between them:
>
> ```css
> table { 
>   border-collapse: separate;
>   border-spacing: 0; 
>   border: 1px solid #000;
> }
>
> th, td, caption {
>   border: 1px solid #000;
> }
> ```
>
> In Firefox at least, the 1px borders will add up to the desired 2px
>   rendered border, avoiding the rounding problem on the way. Safari
>   still leaves a gap. Alternatively, you can hide the problem by not
>   using a border or background colour on your caption. The problem is
>   still there; you just won’t see it. This is probably the simplest and
>   most effective solution.

---

#### TL;DR - gimme tha codez!

You have, then, several choices to tackle this pickle:

- **Lose the border**, and you have no issue. <sup>[**(Demo)**](http://cssdesk.com/S8VBy)</sup>
- **Live with it**, if you must have a background on the header and a 1 pixel border.
- **Use a wider border** (say, 2 pixels) by applying 1 pixel border to cells, headings and captions, set border spacing to 0 and collapse borders by `separate`. <sup>[**(Demo)**](http://cssdesk.com/Sjcuw)</sup>
- **Don't use background/border colors on the headings** (or captions), effectively hiding the problem away. <sup>[**(Demo)**](http://cssdesk.com/jXnvD)</sup>